# sql pivot text based on key then sum on col

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I need to pivot the following rows based on detailkey field

```
Name    Surname    ForeignKey    DetailKey    Value   Reference    plusorminus
----    -----      ----------    ---------    -----   -------      ----- 
John    Jones     1234567        7765         2       Hours        added
John    Jones     1234567        7765         22      Minutes      added
John    Jones     1234567        7766         1       Hours        added
John    Jones     1234567        7766         11      Minutes      added
John    Jones     1234567        7767         0       Hours        deducted
John    Jones     1234567        7767         19      Minutes      deducted
```

The ForeignKey is a common link between the 3 detailkeys.  I need the result to be:

```
Name    Surname    ForeignKey     DetailKey    Hours    Minutes    plusorminus
----    ------     ----------     ----------   -----    ------     --------
John    Jones     1234567         7765         2        22         added
John    Jones     1234567         7766         1        11         added
John    Jones     1234567         7767         0        19         deducted
```

And then I am to insert the final result to a new table, which is a calculation of all of the rows with the same ForeignKey.

```
Name    Surname    ForeignKey      Hours    Minutes    plusorminus
----    ------     ----------      -----    ------     --------
John    Jones     1234567         3        14          added
```

Can anyone help please?

Updated code:

```
SELECT  ( [Userforename] + ' ' + [Usersurname] ) AS OperativeName ,
        formresultkey ,
        parentdetailkey ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN FormelementReference = 'hours_entererd' THEN Value
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS Hours ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN formelementReference = 'minutes_entered' THEN Value
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS Minutes ,
        ( CASE WHEN formelementreference = 'added_deducted' THEN Value
               ELSE NULL
          END ) AS Action ,
        ( CASE WHEN formelementreference = 'COMMENTS' THEN Value
               ELSE NULL
          END ) AS Comments ,
        ( CASE WHEN formelementreference = 'JobRef' THEN Value
               ELSE NULL
          END ) AS JobRef ,
        ( CASE WHEN Formelementreference = 'operative_id' THEN Value
               ELSE NULL
          END ) AS Operative ,
        formresultdate AS Submitted_Date ,
        userjobtitle AS Job ,
        userdeviceid
FROM    [table 1]
GROUP BY [ParentDetailKey] ,
        [UserForename] ,
        [UserSurname] ,
        [FormResultKey] ,
        FormResultDate ,
        UserJobTitle ,
        userdeviceid ,
        CASE WHEN FormelementReference = 'hours_entererd' THEN Value
             ELSE 0
        END ,
        CASE WHEN formelementReference = 'minutes_entered' THEN Value
             ELSE 0
        END ,
        CASE WHEN formelementreference = 'added_deducted' THEN Value
             ELSE NULL
        END ,
        CASE WHEN formelementreference = 'COMMENTS' THEN Value
             ELSE NULL
        END ,
        CASE WHEN formelementreference = 'JobRef' THEN Value
             ELSE NULL
        END ,
        CASE WHEN Formelementreference = 'operative_id' THEN Value
             ELSE NULL
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

I have provided a partial solution to give you the flavour:

```
select
     Name
    ,SurName
    ,ForeignKey
    ,sum(case when Reference = 'Hours' then Value else 0 end) as Hours
from Table1
group by
     Name
    ,SurName
    ,ForeignKey
```

You still have to expand this for the columns DetailKey,Minutes,plusorminus for a complete solution.

the expression `case when plusorminus='plus' then +1 else -1 end` can be used later to properly assign a sign to your values inside the `sum(...)`.

Comment: Thankyou for this help, although once I have put in the case statements for the other columns, and then added them to the group-by statement I am left with the same number of rows just the values have been separated into corresponding columns, with plenty of Nulls and 0's inside the results. Can you shed any light on this please?  I guess it's me somewhere!  It seems that I have to have each of the columns in the select statement in the group by, which is correspondingly the problem.  Thanks

Comment: @user3735855: Note that the difference between `,ForeignKey` and `,sum(case when Reference = 'Hours' then Value else 0 end) as Hours
` is critical; and leaving out the latter structure typically causes the problem you are describing.

Comment: Thankyou Pieter, I have added the code I have amended to the question to give you an idea of where I am at.  Thanks for your help.